# Creating correct application pool in InstallShield 2012 Spring LE

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, installshield

How to create (or select if already created) application pool during setup of the web application in InstallShield 2012 Spring LE? The application pool should have specific features to allow 32 bit applications, NETWORK SERVICE user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition is very crippled compared to InstallShield 2012 Professional edition with regards to IIS ASP.NET configuration (and other things).

So either upgrade to Pro or "augment" InstallShield using merge modules authored with Windows Installer XML.  WiX has an IIS extension that can do what you want.  See the following blog article for a related high level overview:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

Comment: many thanks, does pro version provide simple application pool configuration if I upgrade?

Comment: Yes. It exposes almost everything you need in IIS.  Occasionally though I've seen properties that require a call to AppCmd.exe to set.